# get the particular field value from mongodb

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb i saved document like this.

```
"Angela_Merkel": {
        "birthPlace": "Hamburg,West_Germany",
        "thumbnail": "http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Angela-Merkel-2014.jpg?width=300",
        "almaMater": "Leipzig_University",
        "birthDate": "1954-07-17",
        "spouse": "Joachim_Sauer"
    }
```

There are many person's information like this way. Now if I want to get all the information of "Angela_Merkel" or only a particular like "birthdDate" of "Angela_Merkel" then what will be the query?

Comment: Post some code - show us what you have tried

Comment: I tried, like db.person.find({Angela_Merkel})

Comment: Your schema could do with some redesign as you should avoid storing dynamic keys, instead you can convert those dynamic keys to key-value pairs as elements and store them in an array? e.g. `people: [{ id: "Angela_Merkel", "birthPlace": "Hamburg,West_Germany", ...}, { id: "Walter_Storp", "birthPlace": "Schnecken, East Prussia", ...}]`. That way it's much easier to query, as it is currently you might have to do some complex Map-Reduce operations to achieve the desired result.

Comment: better to use `name`:`"Angela_Merkel"`, and leave the id to be `ObjectId`

Comment: So, there is no easy way to get  only the value of a particular key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like chridam says would be more practical that you refactor your documents like this:

```
{"name": "Angela_Merkel", 
"birthPlace": "Hamburg,West_Germany",
"thumbnail": "http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Angela-Merkel-2014.jpg?width=300",
"almaMater": "Leipzig_University",
"birthDate": "1954-07-17",
"spouse": "Joachim_Sauer"
}
```

Inside the "people" collection (Its a convention name the collections as plurals, beeing a set of documents)

Then you could do:

```
db.people.find({"name":"Angela Merkel"},{"_id":0," "birthdDate":1 })
```

To get:

```
{"birthDate": "1954-07-17"}
```

---

Anyway you can get with your document what you want this way:

"birthDate":

```
db.person.find({"Angela_Merkel.birthDate": "1954-07-17"})
```

or all the info:

```
db.person.find({"Angela_Merkel": { $exists: true}})
```

But doesn't have much sense do it this way.

*PD: Edited to include last part.*